# Kotlin Dokka - Can't find Dokka task in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, code-documentation

I am new to Kotlin and Dokka; 
Following wikis and tutorials I've tried to setup my project for dokka documentation tool with the following lines in gradle build files:

In project gradle file:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:0.9.15"
```

In module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'
```

Android studio version is 2.3.3

After Sync, project rebuild and Android studio restart I expected a dokka task appear in "Tools"/"Task & Contexts"/"+ Open Task" but I can't see any.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dokka task should appear in the Gradle tasks list, check the Gradle panel that's on the right by default:

[image]